# USING to join multiple tables with same field

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables, each with a common field `QuestionnaireId`.

I am wondering if there is any difference in output or performance difference between using `USING` on the field in each join or by specifying the `ON` `QuestionnaireId` relations between each join.

Case A:

```
Select * FROM 
    StudyQuestionnaire
    INNER JOIN QuestionnaireScore USING (QuestionnaireScoreId)
    INNER JOIN Questionnaire USING (QuestionnaireScoreId)
    INNER JOIN QuestionnaireScoreTags USING (QuestionnaireScoreId);
```

Case B:

```
Select * FROM 
    StudyQuestionnaire SQ
    INNER JOIN QuestionnaireScore QS ON SQ.QuestionnaireScoreId = QS.QuestionnaireScore
    INNER JOIN Questionnaire Q ON QS.QuestionnaireScoreId = Q.QuestionnaireScoreId
    INNER JOIN QuestionnaireScoreTags QST ON Q.QuestionnaireScoreId = QST.QuestionnaireScoreId;
```

Comment: USING is just shorthand notation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: There is a difference in output, if you are using `SELECT *`. The `ON` query will show four `QuestionnaireScoreId` columns, the `USING` query will show one.

Comment: other than number of outputted fields though, the overall joining is the exact same right? Also forgot that they are not all inner joins, some may be left joins.

Comment: Performance wise it's the same